# Gradle tasks are disabled in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-task

I'm trying to create a **.jar** file for my eclipse project. Through export option, I am able to create **.jar**, but I want to use **Gradle build task** to do so. Problem is that, all tasks are disabled for this particular project only, as showing in the following image...

[image: Gradle Tasks]

For another project, these **Gradle tasks** are working fine. See its build.gradle file...

```
apply plugin : 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group:"org.apache.pdfbox", name:"pdfbox", version:"2.0.6"
    compile group:"org.apache.pdfbox", name:"pdfbox-tools", version:"2.0.6"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'org.json:json:20180130'

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

It's settings.gradle file contains a single line that is...

```
rootProject.name = 'schedule-extractor'
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: unrelated to your question, but the current version of PDFBox is 2.0.9.

Comment: I've tried with that also

Answer (score 6):

Have you check this buildship's issue:
https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/511

The following comment resolved it for me (I was having the same problem) :
https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/511#issuecomment-367392031

> For those who had a similar problem in include builds - Check the file
>   `.setting/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs` whether the
>   `connection.project.dir` property is empty. If not, make it empty. In
>   my case the grayed tasks become green again.

Comment: For nested projects I need to set the property to the location of the parent project, e.g. `connection.project.dir=../..`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It happened when I was using [composite build concept of Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). According to this approach, One build could be dependent on another build. In this case, the projects may behave like this.

For example, have a look on my composite build setup in settings.gradle...

```
rootProject.name = 'BackendRESTServices'
includeBuild ('../Algorithms') 
includeBuild ('../Utilities')
```

Now I won't be able to build *Algorithms* & *Utilities* projects from **Gradle Tasks** tab as shown in the attached image of question.